# transfer files via Wifi in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am looking out to check if its possible to transfer a file between 2 iPhone devices or between iPhone device and PC/Mac through Wifi. 
If its possible is there any size constraint to the file?

BR,
Suppi

Answer (score 1):

Use bonjour to search for devices. Then use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to send and receive data. It works like a charm.