# How to transfer a file created in an ios app to the mac

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

i'm starting the implementation of a feature for transfer some files (lets say csv files) created in an ios app to the mac.

But i've made some reading about the subject without anything conclusive.

So, can anyone point me a direction to follow in order to achieve my goal ? I need, somehow to access the files created on my app throw the mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File transfer from iOS App to Mac App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922118/file-transfer-from-ios-app-to-mac-app). Also see [How to send file from iPhone to mac over bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314843/how-to-send-file-from-iphone-to-mac-over-bluetooth) and [transfer files via Wifi in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007528/transfer-files-via-wifi-in-iphone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ITunes [file sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094).
2. iCloud.
3. Network transfer.  (This third party [library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) works with iOS and OSX)

Comment: iCloud sucks - it has obscene Terms of Service (seriously, read it). I never agreed to it, and I expect others have boycotted it too. As a matter of fact, all clouds probably suck (unless you are running your own private cloud).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try your first and third options. Thanks a lot

Comment: iTunes file sharing work properly for my needs. Thanks